# What's the meaning of "Fait en deux exemplaires originaux à" ?

Tags: formulation

I'm filling up a non-disclosure agreement and got the below statement.

What's the meaning of "Fait en deux exemplaires originaux à": ..... Le:......

The English translation is also given, but it's weird. I guess i need to fill in my location city in the first blank and the date on second blank. Is this correct? I have attached the exact statement in an image below:

[image: A Picture of the statement]

Comment: The English text doesn't match the French one, that might be what you find weird. What is written literally translates to: *Two original documents issued in: ...  on: ...*

Comment: as usual, English is not very precise, moreover “copy” is ambiguous (two copies of the original document, or two original documents?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't find this weird, it's a contract made in two copies, signed by the two parties at the same time so that both get the same legal paper at the same time.

There is no reason why one party gets a "better" version of the contract, and this is what we get all the time when we sign a contract in France.

Indeed, the first blank is the city where you are signing and the second one is the day when both parties signed.

Comment: Thanks! I guess this is a standard NDA in France, will have to witness more of these when I come to France....

Answer (score 2):

Well it is weird in French too. The meaning is that the original document counts as "one copy" and its copy as a "second copy", both of which should be signed by both parties.

To my understanding, this is a way to allow both parties to have an "original contract" in hands. Otherwise, one party would have the original document and the other party would not. With "signing 2 (original) documents", both parties have the original document.

Comment: I see ! Thanks for the explanation. If i fill in my residential city's name in the first blank, will it make sense?

Comment: Matthieu has answered, ignore my above comment!